# How to find the data on which the Canvas is drawn

Tags: javascript

Please tell me, there is a website, there is a "canvas" on the website on which the graph is rendered.

The data for the graph comes via websocket And after that the browser renders them to the graph.

When you hover the mouse cursor over the graph, a tooltip pops up with data for the point on the graph that the mouse is pointing at.
This data is temporarily embedded in the DOM and can be intercepted via Mutationobserver. After removing the mouse from the graph, this data disappears from the DOM.

But how can find where the data itself is stored - according to which the graph was built??
Or where is the data itself stored - for which a hint pops up and for which this data is temporarily embedded in the DOM ?

Comment: Why don't you provide a minimal runnable example to repoduce your problem?

Comment: @Reporter, and what exactly is an example ?

Comment: *The data for the graph comes via websocket* - you can use devtools to see that. It can be easy to implement a (relative) mouse position to a graph point conversion function.

Comment: @IT goldman, I can intercept websocket data, but it's not very convenient, it's a backup option.
I 'm wondering if this can be done using javascript functions - after all , this data must be stored somewhere ?

Comment: The data doesn't have to be stored (and probably shouldn't be). If the data is pulled and then displayed on a graph, it probably isn't stored in a global variable, meaning once the function that pulled it completes, the variables holding the data are gone. I would think you will need to look at whatever functions/code is being called to build/display the graph.

Comment: @EssXTee, Please explain how to view these functions?

Comment: I would need to know more. Without any actual code or anything to view I cannot give you anything specific. If the graph loads when the page loads, you're going to want to view the source and look for any load events that would trigger a function to pull and display the data. If there is something that needs to be clicked to display the graph, look at the click events for those buttons/links. There will be an event on the page  that calls a function to pull and display the data, so you start your search with the events and go from there.